# Unfortunately app has stopped working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator, classcastexception

I am new to android application development. I was doing this tutorial app.It's a very simple one. It adds one and subtracts one from the counter.When I run it in the emulator ,it says "Unfortunately tutorial has stopped working." There are no errors in the code. The API level is 17. Please help me out.

Code for java:

```
public class Startingpoint extends Activity {
  int counter=0;   
  Button add,subtract; 
  TextView display; 

  @Override    
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    setContentView(R.layout.startingpoint);    
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);    
    subtract= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubtract);   
    display= (Button) findViewById(R.id.text);    
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override   
      public void onClick(View v) {   
        counter++;  
        display.setText("The total is " + counter);   
      }   
    });   

    subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override 
      public void onClick(View v) {
        counter--;
        display.setText("The total is " + counter);
      }

    });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.startingpoint, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Layout code in xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
              android:orientation="vertical" >  

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"    
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Your total is 0"
              android:textSize="35dp"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button   android:layout_width="250dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Add One" 
              android:layout_gravity="center" 
              android:textSize="25dp"
              android:id="@+id/bAdd"/>

     <Button  android:layout_width="250dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Subtract One" 
              android:layout_gravity="center" 
              android:textSize="25dp"
              android:id="@+id/bSubtract"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the logcat :

```
03-02 02:45:10.730: D/AndroidRuntime(780): Shutting down VM
03-02 02:45:10.730: W/dalvikvm(780): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tutorial.example.tutorial/tutorial.example.tutorial.Startingpoint}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at tutorial.example.tutorial.Startingpoint.onCreate(Startingpoint.java:22)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-02 02:45:10.750: E/AndroidRuntime(780):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Next time, just post your code here, and with proper formatting. Double spaced code (to me at least) is less readable.

Comment: *"There are no errors in the code."* - I think you mean there are no *compilation* errors.  Clearly, there was at least one error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
display= (Button) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

should be

```
display= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Since `display` is supposed to reference a `TextView` instance, but you're explictly casting into a `Button`, and these are **not** compatible types.

Comment: Thanks,it worked!! Also, Which device to select while creating a new Android Virtual Device ? It seems pretty confusing to me.

Comment: @user2125722 glad to hear it worked! Since you are new, and your issue is in fact solved, make sure you read [how does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so you understand how accepting works. As for your followup - it depends what API features you want to use. I say choose the Nexus 7 or Galaxy nexus profiles if you're on the new ADT plugin. I personally use 2.2 and 4.1.x for testing. For a bit more info, skim through [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

As you got the answer from A-C this time, but for next time in android application development a important suggestion:

Always see the logcat for error, and see the "Caused by:" tag, It specifies what was the cause of the problem with sufficient detail, Also see the line no that caused that error.
And try to find what can be wrong with that line of code.

For example: in your logcat it is showing-

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button 
at tutorial.example.tutorial.Startingpoint.onCreate(Startingpoint.java:22)
```

So you can try to read the log, and you will understand that in your file `Startingpoint.java` at `line 22` which is located in `onCreate` method the error is `android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button`. So you can easily remove your errors without any help.
Hope that helps not only you current problem but prevented your future time and efforts.